# How to use STM32 IDE with microROS + FreeRTOS?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the title says. How do I incorporate the STM32 IDE into my development workflow? Alternatively, is there a suggested development workflow that is better?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383362/how-to-use-stm32-ide-with-microros-+-freertos?/) by [Bhavesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/77966/bhavesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have instructions for that here: https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_stm32cubemx_utils#using-this-package-with-stm32cubeide

---

Originally posted by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) with karma: 443 on 2021-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bhavesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/77966/bhavesh/) on 2021-07-28**:
Thanks! Is there an equivalent for ROS2 Foxy?

**Comment by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) on 2021-07-28**:
There is a foxy branch in this repo that should work

**Comment by [Bhavesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/77966/bhavesh/) on 2021-07-28**:
That's great! Is only the U(S)ART transport supported by this method? Or is UDP/Ethernet supported too? I didn't see it in the README

**Comment by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) on 2021-07-28**:
Only USART, feel free to contribute if you port the UDP transports.